# DokuWiki - Latex - libjpeg.8.dylib requires a newer version?

Tags: latex, dokuwiki

I'm trying to use the LaTex-Plugin for DokuWiki. When I run the LaTeX troubleshooter I get this error:

[image]

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/identify
  Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
```

I've no idea how to upgrade it to version 13. Any kind of help is appreciated!
John